# IIS 6 on Windows 2003 to IIS 8 on Windows 2012 migration RSS

Tags: iis, load-balancing

We are migrating applications on Windows 2003 IIS 6 Webfarm to IIS 8 on Windows 2012 as W2K3 has reached EOS. We have a single website under which there are 40 applications on a intranet web farm (4 load balanced servers). Eg

```
Website1

   ->app1

    ->app2

    -> app3 etc
```

....     ->app40

translating to http://website1/app1, http://website1/app2 ....and so on

We analysed all the applications (different code base/config and not inter dependencies between them) and found 38 out of the 40 can be hosted on the new platform with just configuration changes, while 2 other apps require significant work due to internal components dependencies. Can we migrate these 38 apps to a new 2012 server leaving behind the 2 apps on the old server retaining the same URL. The problem we have is since it has one virtual ip during cut-over to the new server we might have to move all or none.

I would like to get expert advice to mitigate the problem. we do not want the entire project timelines to be jeopardized due to only 10% of the apps..Please advice

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer for this. It is possible to change the netscaler load balancer configuration to route to specific servers based on url